# Is there a way to pass a variable from an awk statement to a bash function as an argument?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to look a for some specific values from (such as 1 or 4 and 2 or 3) a text file using an `awk` statement in a bash script. If this value is found in the file (within the `awk` statement), then I want to call a function from outside the `awk` statement and pass it the found value as an argument.

My questions: (1) Is this possible? If so then how? (2) If it is not possible or there is a better way, then how?

Note that I am skipping the first two lines of the text file when searching the file. Let me know if further explanation is required.

file.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row1  1     4     7        
row2  2     5     8         
row3  3     6     9
```

The actual function `retrieve` is much more complex than this simplified example. So I need to make a call to this function because I don't want to put this in the `awk` statement.

EDIT 1: I am using GNU AWK

EDIT 2: Lets say I have another function if 2 or 3 are found. How will it work then?

```
function retrieve {
    if [[ "$1" == "1" ]]; then
        echo "one beer on the wall"
    elif [[ "$1" == "4" ]]; then
        echo "four beers on the wall"
    fi
}

function retrieve2 {
    if [[ "$1" == "2" ]]; then
        echo "two beers on the wall"
    elif [[ "$1" == "3" ]]; then
        echo "three beers on the wall"
    fi
}

awk -F '\t' '
    FNR < 2 {next}
    FNR == NR {
        for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) 
        {
            if (($i == 1) || ($i == 4))
                printf(%s, "'retrieve "$i" '")    # Here is the problem

            if (($i == 2) || ($i == 2))
                printf(%s, "'retrieve2 "$i" '")    # Here is the problem
        }
    }

' file.txt
```

Comment: If your version of `awk` supports it, just define `retrieve` as an `awk` user-defined function, rather than try to mix `bash` and `awk` like this.

Comment: @chepner I am using GNU AWK. The bash script I have is fairly long and am only using the `awk` statements when finding stuff in files. If I define the function `retrieve` (which is more complex than the example I gave in the question description) in every `awk` statement, then my script will be very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

skip awk and do everything in bash

```
tail -n +3 file.txt | while read -r ignored c1 c2 c3; do
  echo "$c1"
  echo "$c2"
  echo "$c3"
done | while read -r value; do
  if [ "$value" -eq 1 -o "$value" -eq 4 ]; then
    retrieve "$value"
  elif [ "$value" -eq 2 -o "$value" -eq 3 ]; then
    retrieve2 "$value"
  fi
done
```

explanation

- the `tail` skips the first two lines
- the first while loop serializes the table values while ignoring the first column
- the second while loop examines each value and decides which function to call
- both while loops together roughly do what your awk script did.

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent in answering my question. But My problem is a little more complex. See the `EDIT 2` that I have posted in my question.

Comment: the example in your edit is still doable with the stdout-pipe-stdin idiom. you just need to expand the if in the bash function. as far as i can tell from the information i have i think you are better off writing everything in awk, or reduce the awk to minimum and put the logic in bash functions, or to use another language altogether, for example python.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use bash because my boss said so. I also don't know python (2.7 I'm assuming and not 3.0). How do I expand the `if` in my bash function?

Comment: see new answer. by the way: awk is a programming language fully independent of bash, just like python is. so if your boss is saying only bash then awk is also out of the game.

Comment: +1; while looping in shell code is generally not a good idea for performance reasons, it makes sense here, given the constraints. Is it just a stylistic choice not to use the native `bash` constructs `[[ $value -eq 1 || $value -eq 4 ]]` or `(( value == 1 || value == 4 ))`? (On a side note - I doubt it matters IRL: the `[[` form with unquoted variable references is the fastest conditional form in `bash`.)

Comment: @lesmana Thanks for this answer! I will look into python if necessary but this will do for now. +1

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a shell function directly from an awk script. Your choices are:

1. Save each function in a separate script file and call that script from awk, or
2. Have awk pass some value back to shell to tell it which function to invoke.

Comment: Thank you. I am now trying to find a way to do the second choice. Is there a way to store the values in an array from `awk`?

Comment: As a special case of 2.: `eval`ing output from awk is as close as you can get to "calling shell function in a script from awk: see answer for [cross-post on U&L SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145787/22886).

Comment: You cannot call them _directly_, but you can call _exported_ bash functions _indirectly_ (see my answer) - unsurprisingly, it ain't pretty.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen exported shell functions used like that. An option I suppose... thanks

Answer (score 2):

**While it's not a good idea in general, first and foremost for performance reasons, there IS a - cumbersome - way to call `bash` functions from awk.**

The basic approach is to *export* functions of interest, and then invoke them via `bash -c 'funcName arg ...'` from `awk`.

Here's a proof of concept:

```
# DEFINE the function to be called from awk.
# The function simply prints its arguments one by one in diagnostic fashion.
retrieve() { local a i=0; for a; do echo "\$$((i+=1))=[$a]"; done; }

# EXPORT it, so that bash instances created by awk see the function.
export -f retrieve

# Simple awk program that demonstrates calling retrieve()
# with an argument.
awk -v q=\' 'BEGIN {
    # Define some value to pass to the shell function.
  argToPass="some value"
    # Construct the command line that will call the shell function.
    # Note that since a *function* is being invoked, the arguments
    # must be passed as part of single string passed to -c.
  ec=system("bash -c " q "retrieve \"" argToPass "\"" q)
   # Print the exit code.
  print ec 
  }'
```

Note that every call to the shell function will create *2* child processes, because awk function `system()` invariably invokes `sh` (which may or may not be `bash` on your system), which in this case in turn invokes `bash` explicitly.

- `-v q=\'` is merely a helper variable for making it easier to construct strings with single quotes from inside the awk program. As an alternative, as @EdMorton points out, you could embed `\047` escape sequences directly into awk string literals: `"bash -c \047retrieve \"" argToPass "\"\047"`. <sup>`047` is the octal representation of `0x27`, the ASCII/Unicode codepoint for `'`</sup>
- The command invoked by `system()` writes directly to stdout and stderr and only returns the *exit code*. If you want to capture the output in awk, pipe to `| getline`.
- Argument passing to the shell function should be made more robust for real-world use (e.g., invocation breaks if the value has embedded double quotes; escaping embedded double quotes and also embedded `$` instances (unless shell expansions are desired) is needed ).

Comment: Thanks for that post, I learned something new. +1! FWIW I've used the `q` approach before but I've pretty much settled on using `\047` to embed quotes in awk scripts now, mainly so I don't need to construct strings from concatenating literal strings and variables (e.g. `q "foo" q` vs `"\047foo\047"`), it just looks a bit cleaner IMHO.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @EdMorton; my pleasure. Thanks for the q-tip (if you will): the `\047` approach sounds handy. I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't accept this answer - it is just following on (and hopefully helping out) from Ed's answer and your further question.

Yes, you can store the output of `awk` in a bash array, like this:

```
array=( $(awk 'BEGIN{print 1,2,3}') )

echo ${array[0]}
1
echo ${array[1]}
2
echo ${array[2]}
3
```

Comment: Better to use `read -ra` to prevent accidental pathname expansion: contrast `array=( $(awk 'BEGIN{print 1,2,"*"}') )` with `read -ra array < <(awk 'BEGIN{print 1,2,"*"}')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I appreciate the time you took to answer my question. +1